# How to debug a query where the inner query is giving result but the Outer query is not giving any Output for some columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting the Output as NULL for these columns  RR ,WR ,RR_WR_RATE,RR_WR,DP_RATE,DP,TOTAL  from Outer query , although My inner query is giving some value  for these columns , screenshot is attached , Please tell how to debug the issue .

```
     SELECT  TRAIN_GAUGE, MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE, TRANSPORT_DAYS, A.RR, A.WR, (RR+WR) AS 
       RR_WR_RATE, ROUND((RR+WR)*TRANSPORT_DAYS) AS RR_WR, DP AS DP_RATE,
      ROUND( DP*TRANSPORT_DAYS) AS DP, (ROUND((RR+WR)*TRANSPORT_DAYS)+ROUND(DP*TRANSPORT_DAYS)) AS TOTAL
      FROM(   
  ------------------------Inner Query Starts-------------------------------------------------      
      SELECT DISTINCT A.TRAIN_GAUGE, A.MONTH, A.YEAR, A.SCHEDULED_ZONE, A.TRANSPORT_DAYS, 
      (SELECT RATE_IN_RUPEES FROM COST_DATA WHERE CLASS_GAUGE=A.TRAIN_GAUGE AND HEAD_CODE='PRQ' 
          AND VALID_FROM<= TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 12:00:00 AM','DD-MM-RRRR 
         HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM')
      AND VALID_TO>=TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 11:59:59 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS 
      PM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS PM') ) AS RR,

     (SELECT RATE_IN_RUPEES FROM COST_DATA WHERE CLASS_GAUGE=A.TRAIN_GAUGE AND HEAD_CODE='MCF' 
               AND VALID_FROM<= TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 12:00:00 AM','DD-MM-RRRR 
    HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM')
      AND VALID_TO>=TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 11:59:59 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS 
    PM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS PM') ) AS WR,  

    (SELECT RATE_IN_RUPEES FROM COST_DATA WHERE CLASS_GAUGE=A.TRAIN_GAUGE AND HEAD_CODE='KPP' 
            AND VALID_FROM<= TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 12:00:00 AM','DD-MM-RRRR 
     HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS AM')
      AND VALID_TO>=TO_DATE(TO_DATE('01-'||A.MONTH||'-'||A.YEAR||' 11:59:59 PM','DD-MM-RRRR HH:MI:SS 
     PM'),'DD-Mon-RRRR HH:MI:SS PM') )  AS DP 
      FROM(  
      SELECT DISTINCT TRAIN_GAUGE, MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE, SUM(TRANSPORT_DAYS) AS TRANSPORT_DAYS  
      FROM(         
      SELECT MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE,  TRAIN_NUMBER,
      CUMMULATIVE_LOAD,  GRAND_TOTAL, TRANSPORT_DAYS,  TRAIN_TYPE,TRAIN_GAUGE,TRAIN_SRC, TRAIN_DSTN, 
          OWNING_RLY, DIVISION, SERIAL_NUMBER, 
      EVENT_ORDER
      FROM TRN_MTHLY_RPT
      WHERE OWNING_RLY='NR'
      AND MONTH=01 
      AND YEAR=2021 
      AND TRAIN_GAUGE='BG' 
      AND ACTL_FLAG=9
      AND  TRAIN_TYPE IN (SELECT TRAIN_TYPE FROM GROUP_MAP WHERE GROUP_ID IN (SELECT 
      REGEXP_SUBSTR('ALL','[^|]+', 1, LEVEL)
      AS VALU FROM DUAL  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('ALL', '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL))
      )GROUP BY TRAIN_GAUGE, MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE
      )A
------------------Inner Query Ends ---------------------------
      )A ORDER BY MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE,TRAIN_GAUGE
```

Output of Inner query is :

[image]

Comment: Things like `TO_DATE(TO_DATE(` are always at least an amber flag, because they are at best unnecessary and at worst a source of bugs. Generally speaking this is a hard piece of code to understand. If you want us to help you should post the table DDL statements, and some sample data which produces the problem you describe. At least then we would be able to investigate it properly, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If your inner query works, then start with a simple select from it and modify it piece by piece. Start with a selecting everything, then narrow down.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(<inner query>
)
```

It is unclear what "unable to get output" means - I'm assuming you get no rows ?

If you do this, you'll see what is wrong. In this case, you are aliasing the inner query as "A" but inside your inner query you're also aliasing another query as "A" - that is confusing so probably it is taking the wrong alias. To solve it, remove the references to "A" in the outer query.

```
     SELECT  TRAIN_GAUGE, MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE, TRANSPORT_DAYS, RR, WR, (RR+WR) AS 
       RR_WR_RATE, ROUND((RR+WR)*TRANSPORT_DAYS) AS RR_WR, DP AS DP_RATE,
      ROUND( DP*TRANSPORT_DAYS) AS DP, (ROUND((RR+WR)*TRANSPORT_DAYS)+ROUND(DP*TRANSPORT_DAYS)) AS TOTAL
      FROM(   
  ------------------------Inner Query Starts-------------------------------------------------      
...
------------------Inner Query Ends ---------------------------
      )  ORDER BY MONTH, YEAR, SCHEDULED_ZONE,TRAIN_GAUGE
```

Comment: I am not getting values for columns RR , WR ,RR_WR_RATE,RR_WR,DP_RATE,DP,TOTAL

Comment: so if you run your inner query you get values for the columns, but if you run SELECT * FROM inner query you don't ? What is "unable to get output" - do you get NULL values or an error ?

Comment: I am getting the Output as NULL for these columns

Comment: I removed the Alias , also tried with a new Alias still getting NULL for those columns

Comment: It's very hard to help you on this medium, we'd have to post large chunks of code back and forth to try out things. Let me know if you want to chat in a chatroom on stack overflow, that would be easier.

Comment: Is this solved ? Do you mind sharing how what the issue was in the end ?

Comment: Yes sir the issue is rectified , in the Month column , value passed was 1 not 01 , so it was just 1 character due to which timestamp formating wasn't done properly

Comment: In the statement '01-'||A.MONTH||' , Month was 1 not 01 , so I concatenated with 0 and the issue got rectified . Thanks sir for the concern